# Share routerLinkActive among multiple links

Tags: angular

```
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li><a [routerLink]="['/']">Link 01</a></li>
    <li><a [routerLink]="['somepath']">Link 02</a></li>
    ...
    <li><a [routerLink]="['someotherpath']">Link 20</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

I can use the `routerLinkActive` on each of them, but I'm using the same ".active" class for all of them. Is there a way to use some shortcut, or perhaps much elegant way in order to set the active class for each of the links, without actually writing on each of them the `routerLinkActive`?

Comment: no way! you have to do it manually for each element if you want to less the code put the routes into an array and render them via loop

Comment: @BabarBilal yeah, I know about looping... But I'm not thinking it's a good option. Thanks anyway

Comment: I'm shocked this question doesn't have any attention. The current implementation of routerLinkActive is totally not DRY.